# Change text within input tag with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Rates" class="RatesClass">Rates & Fees<br />
```

How can I change that text `Rates & Fees` dynamically, using Jquery?

Thanks!

How about this one that doesn't have a class defined?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Value" name="Values">Values<br />
```

EDIT:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="RatesFees" name="Rates" class="RatesClass">Rates & Fees<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="RatesOnly" name="RatesSpecific" class="RatesClass">Rates (All-In-Rate Only)<br />
```

Comment: From where? You don't need Jquery to change the text, using DOM functions: `yourInput.NextSibling.Data='new text';`

Comment: Generally you would put a `<label>` around "Rates & Fees" and set its `for` attribute to "Rates" so that clicking on the text will also mark the checkbox.  That would also give you the label tag to select on.

Comment: @Martin  The text isn't a child of the input.  It's a sibling and it doesn't have any tags around it so it wold be enclosed in the parent domnode of the input.

Comment: Generally you would also close the input tag at the end using />

Comment: @Endophage Just saw and changed that, I mistook the `<br />` for an end tag...

Comment: @ZeSimon Or do neither, if slandau doesn't write XHTML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest will be to unwrap the `input` DOM element from the jQuery object, and use the native `nextSibling` property to get the text node, then update its value with `data`.

```
$('input.RatesClass')[0].nextSibling.data = "new value";
```

If you're in an event handler, you'd just use `this` to refer to the element.

```
$('input.RatesClass').change(function() {
    this.nextSibling.data = "new value";
});
```

Comment: What about doing it to an element that does not have a class defined, but everything else is defined the same way?

Comment: @slandau: You need some way to select the input. The best way to select it will depend on the actual situation. If you're doing this in an event handler where the handler is on the `<input>`, then just use the `this` keyword, which will refer to the element. I'll update.

Comment: @patrick, check my edit. That input has no class defined and I cannot use the Id with the way you specified, nor the Jquery .text() property.

Comment: @patrick dw The text isn't inside its own domnode so it isn't a sibling of the `<input>`.  `nextSibling` would return the `<br />`

Comment: So there's no way to get at that?

Comment: @Endophage: That's not correct. Everything in the DOM is some type of node. Here the next sibling is a text node. The `nextSibling` property references the next sibling node no matter what it is. It isn't required that it be a type 1 element. It can be a a type 3 text node, or a type 8 comment node for example.

Comment: @slandau: Why can't you use the ID? You need to have some way to select the element. If you can't select it, you can't do very much with it. You haven't provided very much code in your question. Could you please give a broader view of the situation?

Comment: @patrick, basically, your answer worked, however, I have two elements within the same class so I changed the $('input.RatesClass') to $('RatesFees'), to try and access it by Id instead of type and class, and it didn't work.

Comment: @slandau: jQuery uses CSS style selectors, so to select by ID, you need to precede the ID with `#`, so do `$('#RatesFees')`.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add an `id` to the input.

```
<input id="myInput" type="checkbox" name="Rates" class="RatesClass">Rates & Fees<br/>
```

Then in your jQuery.

```
$('#myInput').html('Here is some HTML')
```

Comment: Where did you find `innerHTML` here?